# Orthogonal complete set of functions

Tags: fourier-analysis, taylor-expansion

Every square-integrable function on an interval can be written as a linear combination of e^inx (Fourier series).

Are there any other orthogonal and complete set of functions for square integrable functions besides e^inx?

Are there any orthogonal and complete set of functions that work for *every* function on a finite interval?

Is there some overview of different orthogonal complete set of functions with different conditions on the function, besides square integrable?

And the functions should be linearly independent too.

Comment: Orthogonality implies linear independence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Walsh functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walsh_function), square waves with periods that are dyadic fractions of the interval length, are another family.  There are many more.  You can even define your own-just make a new list that is a blend of two others and solve the orthogonality issue.  For example, if $n$ has an odd number of factors of $2$ dividing it, we can use $e^{inx}+e^{2inx}$ and $e^{inx}-e^{2inx}$ to make another family.  All the  families that I know are countable, so cannot represent arbitrary functions, because we only allow countable sums.